# CSS: Images in different sizes centered inside a list of responsive floating divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of product in a responsive page, each row display 4 product, and the size of each product should be constant for all the products in the page, but adjusted to the size of the screen - i.e. 25% of the screen width.

example https://jsfiddle.net/eliaweiss/otLcf1kn/

```css
.prod {
 width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/634-home_default/-Brown-Ethnic-Earrings-with-AquaMarine-Crystal-And-k-gold-filled-Boho-Chic-TRIBAL-Jewelry-Macram-Gypsy-Belly-Dance-Earring.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/641-home_default/-Tribal-earrings-Brown-Tribal-earrings-Macrame-earrings-Red-wine-Boho-earrings-e-Bohemian-earrings-Indian-earrings-Lotus.jpg" alt="">
 </div> 
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/644-home_default/-Sale-tribal-earrings-Green-gold-and-white-pearl-hoops-micro-macrame-hippie-earrings-boho-tribal-earrings-gypsy-earrings.jpg" alt="">
 </div> 
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/679-home_default/-Sale-tribal-earrings-Silver-and-Red-Classic-macrame-Earrings-with-delicate-GARNET-gemstone-TRIBAL-jewelry-bohemian-gypsy-jewel.jpg" alt="">
 </div>


 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/634-home_default/-Brown-Ethnic-Earrings-with-AquaMarine-Crystal-And-k-gold-filled-Boho-Chic-TRIBAL-Jewelry-Macram-Gypsy-Belly-Dance-Earring.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/641-home_default/-Tribal-earrings-Brown-Tribal-earrings-Macrame-earrings-Red-wine-Boho-earrings-e-Bohemian-earrings-Indian-earrings-Lotus.jpg" alt="">
 </div> 
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/679-home_default/-Sale-tribal-earrings-Silver-and-Red-Classic-macrame-Earrings-with-delicate-GARNET-gemstone-TRIBAL-jewelry-bohemian-gypsy-jewel.jpg" alt="">
 </div>

 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/644-home_default/-Sale-tribal-earrings-Green-gold-and-white-pearl-hoops-micro-macrame-hippie-earrings-boho-tribal-earrings-gypsy-earrings.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to achieve the following:

1. HTML is responsive - product width is always 25% of the screen
2. img display as a square
3. img keep aspect ratio
4. img not croped
5. img is centered to the middle of the square

I can achieve it with JS, see https://jsfiddle.net/eliaweiss/fs7jv4o7/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  product_width = $(".prod").width();
  $(".prod").each(function(i, o) {
    prod = $(o);
    prod.width(product_width);
    prod.height(product_width);
  })
  $(".prod img").each(function(i, o) {
    img = $(o);
    w = img.width()  - 1;
    h = img.height() - 1;
    //console.log("w="+w+", h="+h);
    if ( w == h) return;
    if (h < w) {
        margin = (w - h)/2;
        img.css("margin-top", margin);
        img.css("margin-bottom", margin);
    }

    if (w < h) {
        img.height();
        img.width(w*w/h); // keep ratio
        h = w*w/h;
        margin = (w - h)/2;
        img.css("margin-left", margin);
        img.css("margin-right", margin);
    }    
  })
})
```

```css
.prod {
 width: 21%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}
img {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/634-home_default/-Brown-Ethnic-Earrings-with-AquaMarine-Crystal-And-k-gold-filled-Boho-Chic-TRIBAL-Jewelry-Macram-Gypsy-Belly-Dance-Earring.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/641-home_default/-Tribal-earrings-Brown-Tribal-earrings-Macrame-earrings-Red-wine-Boho-earrings-e-Bohemian-earrings-Indian-earrings-Lotus.jpg" alt="">
 </div> 
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/644-home_default/-Sale-tribal-earrings-Green-gold-and-white-pearl-hoops-micro-macrame-hippie-earrings-boho-tribal-earrings-gypsy-earrings.jpg" alt="">
 </div> 
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/679-home_default/-Sale-tribal-earrings-Silver-and-Red-Classic-macrame-Earrings-with-delicate-GARNET-gemstone-TRIBAL-jewelry-bohemian-gypsy-jewel.jpg" alt="">
 </div>


 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/634-home_default/-Brown-Ethnic-Earrings-with-AquaMarine-Crystal-And-k-gold-filled-Boho-Chic-TRIBAL-Jewelry-Macram-Gypsy-Belly-Dance-Earring.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/641-home_default/-Tribal-earrings-Brown-Tribal-earrings-Macrame-earrings-Red-wine-Boho-earrings-e-Bohemian-earrings-Indian-earrings-Lotus.jpg" alt="">
 </div> 
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/679-home_default/-Sale-tribal-earrings-Silver-and-Red-Classic-macrame-Earrings-with-delicate-GARNET-gemstone-TRIBAL-jewelry-bohemian-gypsy-jewel.jpg" alt="">
 </div>

 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/644-home_default/-Sale-tribal-earrings-Green-gold-and-white-pearl-hoops-micro-macrame-hippie-earrings-boho-tribal-earrings-gypsy-earrings.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

But I want to know if it's somehow possible to achieve with css

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer with css flex

https://jsfiddle.net/eliaweiss/otLcf1kn/1/

```css
 * {box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
 .list {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
 .prod {
   width: 25%;
   border: 1px solid black;
   padding: 2px;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
 }
 img {
   max-width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="list">
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/634-home_default/-Brown-Ethnic-Earrings-with-AquaMarine-Crystal-And-k-gold-filled-Boho-Chic-TRIBAL-Jewelry-Macram-Gypsy-Belly-Dance-Earring.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/641-home_default/-Tribal-earrings-Brown-Tribal-earrings-Macrame-earrings-Red-wine-Boho-earrings-e-Bohemian-earrings-Indian-earrings-Lotus.jpg" alt="">
 </div> 
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/644-home_default/-Sale-tribal-earrings-Green-gold-and-white-pearl-hoops-micro-macrame-hippie-earrings-boho-tribal-earrings-gypsy-earrings.jpg" alt="">
 </div> 
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/679-home_default/-Sale-tribal-earrings-Silver-and-Red-Classic-macrame-Earrings-with-delicate-GARNET-gemstone-TRIBAL-jewelry-bohemian-gypsy-jewel.jpg" alt="">
 </div>


 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/634-home_default/-Brown-Ethnic-Earrings-with-AquaMarine-Crystal-And-k-gold-filled-Boho-Chic-TRIBAL-Jewelry-Macram-Gypsy-Belly-Dance-Earring.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/641-home_default/-Tribal-earrings-Brown-Tribal-earrings-Macrame-earrings-Red-wine-Boho-earrings-e-Bohemian-earrings-Indian-earrings-Lotus.jpg" alt="">
 </div> 
 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/679-home_default/-Sale-tribal-earrings-Silver-and-Red-Classic-macrame-Earrings-with-delicate-GARNET-gemstone-TRIBAL-jewelry-bohemian-gypsy-jewel.jpg" alt="">
 </div>

 <div class="prod">
  <img src="https://esoterica-shop.com/644-home_default/-Sale-tribal-earrings-Green-gold-and-white-pearl-hoops-micro-macrame-hippie-earrings-boho-tribal-earrings-gypsy-earrings.jpg" alt="">
 </div>
</div>
```

This is good enough for most cases, however it generate a rectangle shape instead of a square